# How to sort an array in Ruby to a particular order?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array in particular order given in another array.

EX: consider an array

```
a=["one", "two", "three"]
b=["two", "one", "three"]
```

Now I want to sort array 'a' in the order of 'b', i.e

```
a.each do |t|
  # It should be in the order of 'b'
  puts t
end
```

So the output should be

```
two
one 
three
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As it is, this question makes no sense. The example shows two arrays with the exact same values (only in different order). If you want to iterate the elements in `a` in the order found in `b`, well, iterate `b` and you're done :-) So I guess there are more conditions, maybe items in arrays do not match? is not a "==" between objects what you need but a different kind of equality? show some more meaningful examples.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Array#sort_by is what you're after.

```
a.sort_by do |element|
  b.index(element)
end
```

More scalable version in response to comment:

```
a=["one", "two", "three"]
b=["two", "one", "three"]

lookup = {}
b.each_with_index do |item, index|
  lookup[item] = index
end

a.sort_by do |item|
  lookup.fetch(item)
end
```

Comment: The simplest for small arrays, but note that this is O(n^2) when the problem is O(n).

Comment: @tokland Ok. Supplied a more scalable version.

Comment: exactly, create an auxiliar mapping + sort_by. I'd probably write it `lookup = Hash[b.to_enum.with_index]`, but well, that's just a detail. Btw, did you see my comment to the question? do you remember what the OP had in mind?

Comment: @tokland and I'd probably use `a.sort_by(&lookup.method(:fetch))`. I suspect that even the OP wouldn't remember what they had in mind. Sometimes I do order an array of objects based on an attribute, where there's another array containing values equal to that attribute, though.

Comment: Yeah, equality on a given attribute is very common. And yeah, I know you are a friend of the `&:obj.method(:name)` trick, I remember your blog post about it :-)

Comment: Andrew, your solution is so elegant I can only wish I invented that myself. Thanks.

Comment: We could also write `lookup = b.each_with_index.to_h` or `lookup = b.map.with_index.to_h`

Answer (score 12):

If `b` includes all elements of `a` and if elements are unique, then:

```
puts b & a
```

Comment: If that condition holds then `b&a == b`.

Comment: @PanThomakos, It can include elements and also have others. `%w{ameba bug bird dog horse shark} & %w{horse ameba shark} => ["ameba", "horse", "shark"]`

Comment: I think it's cool that this works, but here are my reservations:

1. Using & (set intersection) to sort arrays is misleading.
2. The code is brittle. If the lists have duplicate elements or are of the wrong size the code breaks. If the implementation of & changes so that elements are no longer sorted the code breaks.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming `a` is to be sorted with respect to order of elements in `b`

```
sorted_a = 
a.sort do |e1, e2|
  b.index(e1) <=> b.index(e2)
end
```

I normally use this to sort error messages in `ActiveRecord` in the order of appearance of fields on the form.

Comment: Why use `sort` when you can use `sort_by`?

Comment: Performance. http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120 Check out the benchmarking.

Comment: My benchmark shows `N` sec for `sort`, `0.07 N` sec for `sort_by` and `0.01 N` for `&`.

Comment: Because in `sort_by` indexes are calculated only once for each element, and in `sort` it could be possible only if it were some caching. And `&` is compiled in Ruby.

Comment: That benchmark in the doc compares `sort` without a block to `sort_by` using a (no-op) block. If you compare `sort` with a block (like the example in this answer) to the corresponding `sort_by` version you'll see that `sort_by` is considerably faster.