# One-liner for sorting small array by a large array containing same values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Say I have 2 arrays like this:

```
# base set
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# sub set
b = [5, 1, 8, 3]
```

What's the optimal way to sort `b` to the same order as `a`?

```
a.sort_like(b) #=> [1, 3, 5, 8]
```

What is this operation called?

Comment: Your receiver and the argument is strange. It would be more natural if it were the other way around.

Comment: either way works for me.

Comment: using this in the code right now, love it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array in Ruby to a particular order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283295/how-to-sort-an-array-in-ruby-to-a-particular-order)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
a & b
```

Comment: The operation is called "set intersection", and does not sort, but it just removes from (the `dup` of) the receiver what's not in the argument. You can go with randomguy's naming.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, I'm not sure about the most efficient way.

```
def sort_like(other)
  items = []
  other.each do |find|
    each do |item|
      items.append item if item == find
    end
  end
  items
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If b is a subset of a, as you have defined, then **the result is going to always be the sorted version of b**. In which case, the you just want `b.sort` (it won't mutate b, it will return a new array with the sorted contents of b).