# ruby - How to remove elements from an array and keep them in a variable in order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like :
`input2 = ["Other", "Y", "X", "Z", "Description"]`

I want to take off the `"Y", "X", "Z", "Description"` and store them in a variable but keep them in that order.
Example :
 `input2 = ["Z", "X", "Y", "Other", "Description"]` we should have :

`input3 = ["Other"]`
`some_variable = ["Z", "X", "Y", "Description"]`

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One-liner for sorting small array by a large array containing same values in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724107/one-liner-for-sorting-small-array-by-a-large-array-containing-same-values-in-rub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def take_it_off(arr, values)
  without = []
  ordered_values = []
  arr.each do |val|
    if values.include? val
      ordered_values << val
    else
      without << val
    end
  end

  return without, ordered_values
end
```

So you can do

```
irb> values = "Y", "X", "Z", "Description"
=> ["Y", "X", "Z", "Description"]

irb> arr = ["Z", "X", "Y", "Other", "Description"]
=> ["Z", "X", "Y", "Other", "Description"]

irb> take_it_off(arr, values)
=> [["Other"], ["Z", "X", "Y", "Description"]]
```

Comment: Seriously, this gets accepted over the solution I posted?  Which, in my opinion, is far more elegant.

Comment: @ChapleyWatson Maybe the OP feels more confortable with the each method and notice you forgot to retrieve the array without the values

Comment: @ChapleyWatson you forgot to put the remainig array element in a variable :)

Comment: @ChapleyWatson See. But if you add that to your question and you can keep it elegant I totally agree yours should be accepted

Comment: Negative.  I gave the proper solution as it allows him to pull the elements out that are needed.  It could have easily been modified with an "unless" instead of "if" to make the switch.

The initial array stays intact and 2 variables can easily be created like so:  
x = get_stuff(input2, 'Other')
y = get_stuff(input2, 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Description')

Comment: That doesn't work if 1: he doesn't know what other values there might be. 2 if he always want the two arrays makes no sense to call a method twice. Not a big deal this last one but if it can be easily done in one "array cycle" why not do it?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu you're absolutely right. Your answer is the right for me. Thank you

Comment: I'm not saying his answer is bad and mine better. Just saying that elegancy is not everything.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu please I want to ask another question.
I have an array of arrays like : `[["anna1", "-16.530533", "99.276929", "anna "], ["anna2", "-12.476601", "99.237414", "anna "], ["anna3", "-5.923410", "99.187951", "anna "], ["anna4", "4.181119", "99.182358", "anna "], ["anna5", "18.350418", "99.453714", "anna "], ["anna6", "33.987519", "99.697253", "anna "], ["anna7", "48.713421", "99.828300", "anna "], ["anna8", "63.028235", "99.988278", "anna "]]`
And I want to retrieve a specific row(by index) of each array and put it in a variable.

Comment: if he doesn't know the values then he's stuck using indexes.  None of the solutions would really work then unless modified to support a range.  The method I posted scales.  It's not just about the elegance.  I don't think it really matters though as the initial question posted by the OP seems wacky to begin with.

Comment: @MehdiKamar something like `[[1,2],[3,4]].map {|e| e[1]}`

Comment: @ChapleyWatson I meant for the "Other". But yes for a beginner it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
def get_stuff(arr, *eles) # or change eles from splat to single and pass an array
  eles.map { |e| e if arr.include?(e) }
end

input2 = ["Other", "Y", "X", "Z", "Description"] 

x = get_stuff(input2, 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Description')
y = get_stuff(input2, 'Other')
p x
#=> ["Y", "X", "Z", "Description"]
p y
#=> ["Other"]
```

Not elegant really but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
input2 = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e]
input3 = input2.slice!(-4..-1) # ! indicates destructive operator
#Or just as well: input3 = input2.slice!(0..4)
input2.inspect
#[:a]
input3.inspect
#[:b,:c,:d,:e]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done using Ruby delete method, and a map. Probably can be even more simplified.

```
def get_stuff(arr=[], eles=[])
  eles.map { |e| arr.delete(e) }
end

a = %w(Other Y X Z Description)
v = %w(Y X Z Description)
r = get_stuff(a, v)

# a is modified to ["Other"]
# r returns ["Y", "X", "Z", "Description"]
```