# Reordering an array in the same order as another array was reordered

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting, ruby-1.9.3

I have two arrays `a`, `b` of the same length:

```
a = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]
b = [b_1, b_2, ..., b_n]
```

When I sort `a` using `sort_by!`, the elements of `a` will be arranged in different order:

```
a.sort_by!{|a_i| some_condition(a_i)}
```

How can I reorder `b` in the same order/rearrangement as the reordering of `a`? For example, if `a` after `sort_by!` is

```
[a_3, a_6, a_1, ..., a_i_n]
```

then I want

```
[b_3, b_6, b_1, ..., b_i_n]
```

**Edit**

I need to do it in place (i.e., retain the object_id of `a`, `b`). The two answers given so far is useful in that, given the sorted arrays:

```
a_sorted
b_sorted
```

I can do

```
a.replace(a_sorted)
b.replace(b_sorted)
```

but if possible, I want to do it directly. If not, I will accept one of the answers already given.

Comment: How do you define the 'same order' for b? Old index -> new index are equivalent for each element of b?

Comment: @MarkThomas I define it as having the same permutation matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Comment: Do you need to save the permutation matrix (or vector, as it may be in this case)?

Comment: @MarkThomas I don't need the permutation matrix.

Comment: Now that you've edited your question, I think it may be useful to save it. Then you can 'apply' it to a and b which would keep the object ids. Since you've already accepted an answer, if it is important to you, you can ask another question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach would be to zip the two arrays together and sort them at the same time.  Something like this, perhaps?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = %w(a b c d e)

a,b = a.zip(b).sort_by { rand }.transpose

p a #=> [3, 5, 2, 4, 1]
p b #=> ["c", "e", "b", "d", "a"]
```

Comment: Your idea seems fine, but is there a way to do it in place? Please see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
ary_a = [ 3, 1, 2] # => [3, 1, 2]
ary_b = [ 'a', 'b', 'c'] # => ["a", "b", "c"]
ary_a.zip(ary_b).sort{ |a,b| a.first <=> b.first }.map{ |a,b| b } # => ["b", "c", "a"]
```

or

```
ary_a.zip(ary_b).sort_by(&:first).map{ |a,b| b } # => ["b", "c", "a"]
```

Comment: Your idea seems fine, but is there a way to do it in place? Please see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 2):

If the entries are unique, the following may work. I haven't tested it. This is partially copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4283318/38765

```
temporary_copy = a.sort_by{|a_i| some_condition(a_i)}
new_indexes = a.map {|a_i| temporary_copy.index(a_i)}

a.each_with_index.sort_by! do |element, i|
  new_indexes[i]
end

b.each_with_index.sort_by! do |element, i|
  new_indexes[i]
end
```

Comment: I was trying to think of something like this, but I don't think the Enumerator class has the modify-in-place versions of methods like map and sort_by.

Comment: Thanks. Doing it like this is what I wanted. I need to see which is faster between using chron/the Tin Man's solution with `replace` or your answer.