# Ruby: Sort array of objects based on array of integers

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

This seems like its fairly simple, and should have been asked before, but everything I find on Stack Overflow doesn't seem to work. I have an array of 4 objects, and I'd like to re-order it in a particular order. So, it looks like this:

```
array = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4]
```

I have another array of integers which represent the desired order of the indices:

```
desired_order = [2,3,0,1]
```

So what I would like to see after ordering `array` properly is:

```
array = [Obj3, Obj4, Obj1, Obj2]
```

I've already figured `sort_by` is the method to use, but I can't seem to come up with the proper syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array in Ruby to a particular order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283295/how-to-sort-an-array-in-ruby-to-a-particular-order)

Comment: @theTinMan. Doesn't seem the same problem, here you already have the indexes.

Comment: I don't know what your task is, but it looks like `array.rotate.rotate` could help *in this case*. Maybe also in other cases? :-P

Comment: Yeah, this was an incredibly rare edge-case on dealing with an out of date CMS. I have no ability to alter how the data was entered, and it has to be rendered in a particular order. Only this one particular item in the entire system is in the wrong order... =\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at) does exactly what you need:

```
array.values_at(*desired_order)
```

Comment: Any idea how this compares benchmark-wise to `map`? In this case it won't matter since I only have 4 items, but for future generations' sake...

Comment: Why a map would be better with more elements? it's exactly the same operation, only that the abstraction already exists in the core (and probably implemented in C)

Comment: Wasn't claiming it was, I was asking the question..Didn't know this is using the same operation as map.

Comment: Yeah, I know, the thing is I don't understand why you are asking. Imagine that you have a million elements to retrieve, you still have an array of a million elements to map, don't you? so there is no difference conceptually. However, since the map is done at Ruby level, and `values_at` at C level, `values_at` should be faster. You can do the benchmarking but I'd very surprised if that's not the case.

Comment: Could you edit this a bit? Looks like `values_at` requires a comma separated list of integers, whereas `desired_order` in my above question is an array of integers, so as written with my code above this would throw an error.

Answer (score 5):

```
desired_order.map{|i| array[i]}
```

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you both, guess sort_by was not the correct method after all :)

Comment: You can also do it with `sort_by`, but it is not as straightforward: `array.sort_by.with_index{|_, i| desired_order.index(i)}` and is much less efficient.

Comment: @Tokland's `values_at` is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you have indexes already, then you can just map them to objects:

```
array = %w[obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4]
desired_order = [2,3,0,1]

desired_order.map{|idx| array[idx]} # => ["obj3", "obj4", "obj1", "obj2"]
```