# Sort Ruby Array of Clothing Sizes

Tags: ruby, sorting

Given the following ruby array:

```
["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"]
```

How do I sort it so that it is in this order?

```
["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]
```

Note that every size is **not always present**.

For history's sake, this was my original implementation.

```
sorted_sizes = []

sorted_sizes << "S" if sizes.include?("S")
sorted_sizes << "M" if sizes.include?("M")
sorted_sizes << "L" if sizes.include?("L")
sorted_sizes << "XL" if sizes.include?("XL")
sorted_sizes << "2XL" if sizes.include?("2XL")
sorted_sizes << "3XL" if sizes.include?("3XL")
sorted_sizes << "4XL" if sizes.include?("4XL")
sorted_sizes << "5XL" if sizes.include?("5XL")
sorted_sizes << "6XL" if sizes.include?("6XL")

sorted_sizes
```

Comment: If every size is not always present, do you want it to appear in the sorted array?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283295/how-to-sort-an-array-in-ruby-to-a-particular-order

Comment: @squiguy, no, I don't want the sorted array to have values not present in the array being sorted.

Comment: Your solution suggests that the array to be sorted never contains duplicates or the sorted array is not to contain duplicates.  Correct?  Note the '`sort_by`' solutions would include duplicates from the array to be sorted in the sorted array, whereas @sawa's solution would not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"] & ["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"]
# => ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]
```

Comment: That's pretty darn clever!

Comment: does not account for repeats.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to do it that can handle repeats:

```
SORT_ORDER = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]

["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL",
 "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"].sort_by { |x| SORT_ORDER.index(x) }
```

Answer (score 4):

I really like @nicooga's version to this problem and would just suggest to wrap the logic in a lambda. That way it can be used in many places throughout the code.

```
clothing_size = ->x{%w(S M L XL 2XL 3XL 4XL 5XL 6XL).index(x)}

size_list = ["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"]

size_list.sort_by &clothing_size
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"] 
sort_order = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]

sort_order - (sort_order - array)
  # => ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "6XL"]
```