# Rails where using array and sorted by the same as the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, database, postgresql, where-clause

it's a pretty complex question to explain using words, so I gonna use code:

Let's imagine the following scenario:

```
User.create name: "bar"
User.create name: "foo"
User.create name: "baz"
```

I want to perform the following query:

```
User.where(name: ["foo", "bar", "baz"])
```

*User* has no *default_scope*

I want to retrieve these 3 records in the following order:

```
<User name:foo>, <User name:bar>, <User name:baz>
```

But, as you may know, rails will return the records in the same order as they were created (Actually I do believe it is the database behavior, rails is just a proxy). Like the next snippet:

```
<User name:bar>, <User name:foo>, <User name:baz>
```

Anyway, Does anyone know if there is a clean way to solve it?

I could use an each and perform the query but it'll end up in an N+1 query and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Use a `name in` and `order by`, or `name in` and sort in Ruby.

Comment: Try User.where(name: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) and then sort items like in default array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283295/how-to-sort-an-array-in-ruby-to-a-particular-order, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961685/sort-an-array-according-to-the-elements-of-another-array

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch all the records from the database at once, and then sort them by the sequence of names in the array:

```
names = %w[ foo bar baz ]
users = User.where(name: names)
sorted_users = users.sort_by { |user| names.index(user.name) }
```

But if you need to get the records in insertion order, you could also get away with just ordering them by the `created_at` timestamp, if present in your table:

```
 users = User.order(created_at: :asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this.

1. Sort in Ruby as fivedigit mentionned.
2. Use a custom ORDER BY SQL condition. Do this if you need to keep the query as an ActiveRecord::Relation, for example if you need to further filter it.

To do this, map each value in order to an integer.

Simple case:

```
User.where(:name => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]).order("CASE name WHEN 'foo' THEN 1 WHEN 'bar' THEN 2 WHEN 'baz' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END")
```

Automatic mapping of query values to integers:

```
field = "name"
values = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
order_when = []
values.each_with_index { |value, index| order_when << "WHEN #{User.sanitize(value)} THEN #{index}" }
order_query = "CASE #{field} #{order_when.join(" ")} ELSE #{values.length} END"
User.where(field => values).order(order_query)
```